# How can i run rethinkdb-dump/export in RethinkDB + Docker

Tags: docker, rethinkdb

When running RethinkDB through Docker: http://dockerfile.github.io/#/rethinkdb, i would like to be able to export datas through "rethinkdb-dump or rethinkdb-export", however it throws me the following error:

```
Failed to move temporary directory to output directory (/tmp/tmpqx0xvM/rethinkdb_dump_2014-01-23T15:57:44): No such file or directory
```

I can correctly access to the RethinkDB admin panel through 192.168.33.10:8080. The command i ran was:

```
rethinkdb-export -c 192.168.33.10:28015
```

Im running Docker + RethinkDB inside the Vagrant (Ubuntu 13.04), i've tried running the same command by installing rethinkdb directly with the python driver, and it works perfectly.

This is the only holdback to let me use Docker + RethinkDB, any help would be appreciated.

Edit: problem solved, see https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1904

Comment: Did you run the export command from inside or outside docker?

Comment: Outside, i ran the command from Vagrant

Comment: Why is the script being run in the /tmp/tmpqx0xvM folder? Perhaps there is not enough space on the partition or some other process is deleting your files.

Comment: The /tmp folder is created by the rethindb-export script, not sure what would be the cause, but i think the temp directory used for export is not created somehow when the rethinkDB is running through docker, the same command "rethinkdb-export -c 192.168.33.10:28015 -d 'some/directory'" works perfectly fine when i run the rethinkdb instance from Vagrant.

Comment: Are there any tables in your database? Dose the dump work if you create a table? The dump script fails with the same error when there are no tables in the database. I have just opened an issue for that bug: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1904

Comment: Oh, you are right, now it works with tables in the database, thanks!

Comment: You might want to edit the question to mark the reason for the problem, or to add your own answer then :-)

Answer (score 0):

As @Atnnn pointed out, RethinkDB when having no tables in the DB would result in an error when starting a `rethindkb export/dump`. A recent version of the Python driver now fixes this problem.